# Checking date and current date in Mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a table named billing, with two columns dates and billno.

when I try to run the query

```
SELECT dates,billno FROM billing WHERE dates=2015-10-31;
```

in **C#**.

I get empty set, but this query works

```
SELECT dates,billno FROM billing;
```

I have one row inserted with exact date and format?

this is the exact code

```
"SELECT dates,billno FROM billing WHERE dates='"+d+"'";
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Probably missing simple quotes

Comment: Please don't do that.  Create a parameter for your query instead.

Comment: Do not concatenate SQL string because you will get SQL Injection. Bind your parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT dates,billno FROM billing WHERE dates='2015-10-31'


SELECT dates,billno FROM billing WHERE DATE(dates)=DATE(NOW())
```

You missed quotes

Hope this helps

Comment: Yep, works like a charm... will accept in three minutes

Comment: Ahhh problem!! "SELECT dates,billno FROM billing WHERE dates='"+d+"'"; what do i do with these?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying  to do

Comment: select the two values based on the date from string d.

Comment: there will be numbers in date, so why you are comparing with `d`

Comment: there u r trying to check with today